# Spring request mapping issue

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have a request mapping like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPic/{moduleName}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JPEG)
```

But above mapping fail when i hit below url

```
/getPic/z012/{80BE26C1-7142-408C-903F-5721EBF5Eá28A}.jpg OR

/getPic/z012/#80BE26C1-7142-408C-903F-5721EBF5Eá28A}.jpg
```

Please help someone, what regex should I add in RequestMapping for my url to work

Comment: ahem... could it be because the mapping is on /loadPhoto/** and you are querying for something in /getPic/ ?

Comment: It is just by mistake. still not working

Comment: Well, the RequestMapping does not take a regexp it takes an ant-style path pattern. You should define it as value="/getPic/z012/*.jpg"